# Ensuring virtual machine survives Fedora clean install

Tags: virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I am running Win 10 in a virtual machine under Fedora 30. I now need to do a clean install of Fedora 32. It is critical that the virtual machine survives this install.

The default location of virtual machines is under `/var/lib/libvirt`, which will will be run over by installation. Because of this, I now created a new pool onto a logical volume that will survive fresh OS install and used `virt-clone` to clone the virtual machine onto this logical volume. The cloned virtual machine is running just fine.

I can see that in the logical volume where the clone is the *only* file is the `.qcow2`-file containing the cloned virtual machine. I have two questions:

1. In order for the virtual machine to survive clean OS installation, is it sufficient that the `.qcow2`-file carries over? Or do I need to copy other information from some other directory?
2. After OS install, how do I tell `virt-manager` about the pool that already exists and the virtual machine that is located there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to at least copy the guest XML configuration files, which are stored under sub-dirs of `/etc/libvirt`.

If you've stored other things like snapshots, further dirs under `/var/lib/libvirt` may need to be preserved.

If you save the XML files somewhere, then in the new install "`virsh define $XMLFILE`" will load the guest into libvirt, such that virt-manager will see it again. You can use virt-manager's storage management UI to tell it about the pool.

Comment: When interpreting your answer, I found the command `virsh dumpxml`, which dumps the XML configuration file of a guest, and according to the manual page, can be used by `virsh create` to create the domain. But, as you wrote, `virsh define` can most likely use the same file. I am not yet sure of the exact difference between `create` and `define`, except that `define` will not start the domain. I see that the XML dump contains path to the `.qcow2` file, which is promising.

Comment: `virsh define $XML` simply saves the config file into libvirt, and you can later boot the guest using `virsh start $GUEST`.   The `virsh create $XML` will boot a guest without ever saving its config on disk, so all trace of it will disappear when it shuts down again.

Comment: Ok. Digging further into this, the topic is pretty interesting. First, it seems that it is also possible to dump pool XML and perhaps use that to automatically define a pool. Second, Ansible - which I always use to automate Fedora installation and setup - has community-supported modules for virtual machine configuration. So, in theory, it might be possible to automate the entire VM setup. The problem is knowing which commands might be destructive. Hence the original title: "Ensuring...".

Comment: One more comment after applying this: you need to define the pool before you define the virtual machine. If you do it the other way round, there will be no default pool and standard programs such as `virsh` will start throwing only errors at you.